# How to Perform Consecutive Counts of Column by Group Conditionally Upon Another Column

Tags: r, sum, aggregate-functions, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I'm trying to get consecutive counts from the Noshow column grouped by the PatientID column. The below code that I am using is very close to the results that I wish to attain. However, using the sum function returns the sum of the whole group. I would like the sum function to only sum the current row and only the rows that have a '1' above it. Basically, I'm trying to count the consecutive amount of times a patient noshows their appointment for each row and then reset to 0 when they do show.  It seems like only some tweaks need to be made to my below code. However, I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere on this site.

```
transform(df, ConsecNoshows = ifelse(Noshow == 0, 0, ave(Noshow, PatientID, FUN = sum)))
```

The above code produces the below output:

```
#Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
#Groups: ID [2]
#
#   PatientID Noshow ConsecNoshows
#       <int>  <int>         <int>   
#1          1      0             0
#2          1      1             4
#3          1      0             0
#4          1      1             4
#5          1      1             4
#6          1      1             4
#7          2      0             0
#8          2      0             0
#9          2      1             3
#10         2      1             3
#11         2      0             0
#12         2      1             3
```

This is what I desire:

```
#Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
#Groups: ID [2]
#
#   PatientID Noshow ConsecNoshows
#       <int>  <int>         <int>   
#1          1      0             0
#2          1      1             0
#3          1      0             1
#4          1      1             0
#5          1      1             1
#6          1      1             2
#7          2      0             0
#8          2      0             0
#9          2      1             0
#10         2      1             1
#11         2      0             2
#12         2      1             0
```

[UPDATE] I would like the consecutive count to be offset by one row down.

Thank you for any help you can offer in advance!

Comment: I wish I could checkmark all your solutions as they all provided exactly as I wanted. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here's another (similar) `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ConsecNoshows := seq(.N) * Noshow, by = .(PatientID, rleid(Noshow))]
df
#     PatientID Noshow ConsecNoshows
#  1:         1      0             0
#  2:         1      1             1
#  3:         1      0             0
#  4:         1      1             1
#  5:         1      1             2
#  6:         1      1             3
#  7:         2      0             0
#  8:         2      0             0
#  9:         2      1             1
# 10:         2      1             2
# 11:         2      0             0
# 12:         2      1             1
```

This is basically groups by `PatientID` and "run-length-encoding" of `Noshow` and creates sequences using the group sizes while multiplying by `Noshow` in order to keep only the values when `Noshow == 1`

Comment: David, I checked your answer as correct because you provided the shortest code to get the job done.

Comment: After performing more work on my model, I found that I actually need the consecutive count result to be offset by one. So if the first two lines are counted as a noshow, the third line should have a 2 in the ConsecNoshows column. Is this possible?

Comment: You could do `df[, ConsecNoshows := shift(ConsecNoshows, fill = 0), by = PatientID]` or similar

Comment: I updated the table in my original question to show the results I'm trying to get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I'm going to start studying the data.table functions and they are proving to be extremely helpful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rle` from `base R` (No packages used). Using `ave`, we group by 'PatientID', get the `rle` of 'Noshow', multiply the `sequence` of 'lengths' by the 'values' replicated by 'lengths' to get the expected output.

```
helperfn <- function(x) with(rle(x), sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))
df$ConsecNoshows <- with(df, ave(Noshow, PatientID, FUN = helperfn))
df$ConsecNoshows 
#[1] 0 1 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1
```

---

As the OP seems to be using 'tbl_df', a solution in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(PatientID) %>%
   mutate(ConsecNoshows = helperfn(Noshow))
#     PatientID Noshow ConsecNoshows
#       <int>  <int>         <int>
#1          1      0             0
#2          1      1             1
#3          1      0             0
#4          1      1             1
#5          1      1             2
#6          1      1             3
#7          2      0             0
#8          2      0             0
#9          2      1             1
#10         2      1             2
#11         2      0             0
#12         2      1             1
```

Comment: Akrun, thank you so much for your solutions. They all worked exactly as intended. I especially like the base R solution you provided.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a helper function to then use whatever implementation you're most comfortable with:

```
sum0 <- function(x) {x[x == 1]=sequence(with(rle(x), lengths[values == 1]));x}

#base R
transform(df1, Consec = ave(Noshow, PatientID, FUN=sum0))

#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% mutate(Consec=sum0(Noshow))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Consec := sum0(Noshow), by = PatientID]
  #    PatientID Noshow Consec
  #        <int>  <int>  <int>
  # 1          1      0      0
  # 2          1      1      1
  # 3          1      0      0
  # 4          1      1      1
  # 5          1      1      2
  # 6          1      1      3
  # 7          2      0      0
  # 8          2      0      0
  # 9          2      1      1
  # 10         2      1      2
  # 11         2      0      0
  # 12         2      1      1
```

Comment: Pierre, your solution is really helpful as it gives me multiple options to use. Thank you for enlightening me to the use of creating a helper function.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way to group consecutive values is to use `rleid` from `data.table`, here is an option from `data.table` package, where you group data by the `PatientID` as well as `rleid` of `Noshow` variable. And also you need the `cumsum` function to get a cumulative sum of the `Noshow` variable instead of `sum`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ConsecNoshows := ifelse(Noshow == 0, 0, cumsum(Noshow)), .(PatientID, rleid(Noshow))]
df
#    PatientID Noshow ConsecNoshows
# 1:         1      0             0
# 2:         1      1             1
# 3:         1      0             0
# 4:         1      1             1
# 5:         1      1             2
# 6:         1      1             3
# 7:         2      0             0
# 8:         2      0             0
# 9:         2      1             1
#10:         2      1             2
#11:         2      0             0
#12:         2      1             1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the first solution that worked Psidom.